# Cross origin error when using cloud functions in back4app

Tags: back4app

```
Getting CORS error when calling cloud function in back4app.

Error:
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/functions/hello' from origin 
  'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access- 
   Control- Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
In client code cloud function implemented in home page 

 home.page.ts:

 Parse.Cloud.run('hello').then(function (ratings) {

   console.log("updated");

 }).catch((error) => {

   console.log(error);

   console.log("fail"); 

 });

 Cloud function:

In back4app added main.js file with cloud code implementation

  main.js:

 Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {

   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

   return 'Hi';    
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be related to the Parse Server version.

Can you please take a look to check what is the Parse Server version that you are using? Please, find this info following [this guide](https://help.back4app.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016081032-Manage-Parse-Server-Version).

If it is 2.X, you must deploy a function with the structure below:

`main.js`:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', function(req, res) {    
   response.success('Hello')
});
```

The code `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` is deprecated. Read more [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#using-the-master-key-in-cloud-code).

If it is the 3.X, you can deploy something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('hello', (req) => {    
   return 'Hello';
});
```

- Check if you have initialized the correct keys on your frontend side.

If it still doesn't work, please contact the Back4App team in the live chat =D